# Is my way of proof correct?

Tags: inequality

**Question** $$$$
prove that :
$$\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{a^2_k})\;>\frac {1}{2}$$
$$where :\;1 < a_1 < a_2< · · · < a_n, a_i∈ N, i = 1, 2 . . . , n $$

**my attempt**

$$a_1 > 1 \implies  a_1 \geq 2$$
$$a_2 > a_1  \implies a_2 > 2\implies  a_2 \geq 3$$
$$. . . $$
$$a_k > k \implies  a_k \geq k+1$$

We know that :
$$a_k \geq k+1 \implies  $$

$$\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{a_k^2})\geq\;\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{(k＋1)^2})$$

Now I will try to simplify this :
$$
\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{(k＋1)^2})＝\prod_{k＝1}^{n}\frac {k(k＋2)}{(k＋1)^2}\\~\\＝(\frac {1×3}{2^2})(\frac {2×4}{3^2})(\frac {3×5}{4^2})...(\frac {n(n＋2)}{(n＋1)^2})\\~\\＝\frac {n＋2}{2(n＋1)}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$$

Then :
$$\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{a_k^2})\geq\;\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$$

In the last :

$$\prod_{k＝1}^{n}(1-\frac {1}{a_k^2})>\frac{1}{2}$$

**That's what I'm looking for**
I want to know if my method of proof is correct ??

Is there a better way than this to prove what is required?

**I appreciate your concern**

Comment: Yes, you are right, but here I do not mean the prime numbers, but the natural numbers.

Comment: Ok ,Thank you for telling me that

Comment: Can you tell if my answer is correct? .

Comment: You have $a_k\ge k+1$, and then $1/a_k\le 1/(k+1)$. May be you should say more how you proceed (after "We know that" a step is missing, because we also have a minus sign). You should say that we obtain $1/a_k^2 \le 1/(k+1)^2$ and then $-1/a_k^2 \ge -1/(k+1)^2$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is my answer to the question correct or incorrect?

Comment: It seems correct, but you should explain how you get the expression $(n+2)/2(n+1)$ from the product.

Comment: This depends on the grading scheme. It is "almost correct", which means, if you are seeking perfection, the same as "incorrect". Perhaps you should change your title, which is not good so far.

Comment: Ok , Thank you .